# Which yields faster code?

Tags: c++, performance

Which compiles to faster code: `pm1 = x * 3;` or `pm1 = x + ( x * 2 );`

Assuming that `x` is either an `int` or a `long`, and it is is running on a modern Win32 Intel box.

Comment: Depends on the compiler. You can check the asm output and/or measure time.

Comment: A good compiler will generate identical code for both.

Comment: Unless there is a short cut for `x*2`, `x*3` should be faster -- it involves only one operation while the other involves two operations.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking?

Comment: @zmbq Unless these aren’t `int`s but `float`s or `double`s, and `-ffast-math` isn’t enabled.

Comment: Irrelevant. The chances of that being your bottleneck are pretty much zero.

Comment: "Assuming that `n` is either an int or a long" - Is that the `n` you neglected to include *anywhere* in the code line ? because as it stands `n` could be *anything* and it won't mean a thing, as it appears nowhere in that equation.

Comment: @RSahu it's possible that two operations together can be faster than a single operation if they're simple enough, and the `*2` could be replaced by a `<<1`. I think integer multiplies are fast enough that this won't be the case, but I don't have data to back it up.

Comment: P.S. Any question that asks "which is faster" **must** be benchmarked, because modern CPUs and compilers are too complex for simple rules of thumb on micro optimizations. Any answer you get is likely to be wrong depending on your specific circumstances.

Comment: Depends, which timezone do you live in and what is the current phase of the moon?

Answer (score 2):

The true answer to your question is: "depends on the platform and compiler settings".

Let us take the case of no optimizations.
There are 3 cases.

### Case 1: Adding the variable 3 times.

The instructions:

```
  MOV Y, 0    ; Set Y to zero.
  ADD Y, Y, X ; Add X to Y and place result in Y.
  ADD Y, Y, X ; Add X to Y and place result in Y.
  ADD Y, Y, X ; Add X to Y and place result in Y.
```

The processor would fetch 4 and process 4 instructions.  The bottleneck may be in the duration to fetch.

### Case 2: Multipy by 2 and add once

The instructions:

```
  MOV Y, 0
  MUL Y, X, 2  ; Multipy X by 2 and store into Y.
  ADD Y, Y, X ; Add X to Y and place result in Y.
```

Note, there is one less instruction, but the multiplication will take longer.  Hard to tell if the multiplication is faster than a fetch.

If we use shifting instead of multiplying by 2:

```
  MOV Y, 0
  SHL Y, X, 1 ; Shift the bits in X left by one bit, place result in Y.
  ADD Y, Y, X ; Add X to Y and place result in Y.
```

This will be faster because shifting by one bit is faster than multiplying.
Is the savings significant?

### Case 3: Multiplying by 3

The instructions:

```
MOV Y, 0
MUL Y, X, 3 ; Multipy X by 3 and place result in Y.
```

There are only 2 instructions, but the multiplication takes longer than shifting or adding.  Is it faster than fetching?  Don't know, that is a performance measurement that is needed.

### Conclusion:

The experiment needs to be profiled on different systems to get proper results.  Multiplying reducing the number of instructions that are fetched from the processor's cache.  However, multiplying is a more complex operation than addition or shifting.  If multiplying is faster than fetching from the cache, then there is some savings.

The big question, is how much execution time is saved?  Not much.  If we assume that the processor takes an average of 100ns to execute an instruction, best case you will have saved 2 instructions or 200 ns.  Considering relative times, User Input is measured in seconds, I/O in milliseconds.  You could gain more time by optimizing User Input or File I/O.

If you gain 200ns, it will be wasted by waiting for User Input or File I/O or for the OS to swap your program with another one.

The productivity lost with these micro-optimizations is substantial.  The time spent researching and profiling this experiment could be better spent developing the remainder of the program and making the program correct and robust.

Comment: Don't assume a shift is faster than a multiply. Perhaps the CPU implements a very fast multiply, or perhaps the multiply can occur in parallel with other operations. Or perhaps the whole operation is limited by how fast the instructions can be fetched or how fast the results can be written to memory. Benchmarking is the only true way to know.